# Как через media query задать стили для экранов с диагональю, меньшей 7 дюймов?

Tags: media-queries, css

Можно ли через media query задать стили для экранов с диагональю, меньшей 7 дюймов?
Если можно, то как?

Comment: Лучше используйте брэйкпоинты в пикселях. В бутстрапе это хорошо сделано - 480, 768, 992...

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку на сегодняшний день разные устройства имеют разное количество пикселей на дюйм, соответственно на двух устройствах с одинакового размера экраном может отображаться по разному. Для примера на старых макбуках с диагональю 13 дюймов разрешение экрана составляет 1280 на 800 пикселей. На этих же компьютерах последних лет разрешение составляет 2560 на 1440(не буду расписывать как можно сделать его не scale'ным).

Не зная вашей задачи могу я уверен что вам следует воспользоваться media queries для того что бы задавать брейкпоинты используя размер экрана в пикселях. Этот подход используют все современные css фрэймворки(bootstrap, material design lite, yaml:4, semantic-ui) и это считается хорошей практикой.

Как альтернативу можно так же использовать меру длинны em как это делают zurb foundation и purecss.